# Generating table of content of lecture notes

Tags: table-of-contents

There are nice notes on quantum computing by John WatrouS:

[https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/QC-notes/](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/QC-notes/)

However, there is without the table of contents. I didn't need exact page number but at least the title of each lecture properly and with correct sequence of lecture.

The separate pdf files also available for each lecture. How can I get the table content page for these notes by combining the pdf file of each lecture.

Comment: If the answer met your request, please accept it by checking the green tick on the left side of the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The same link provides a single file with the collection of all lectures, with correlative page numbers. (`QC-notes.pdf`)

[All 22 lectures in one file](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/QC-notes/QC-notes.pdf)

1. Being a one-time job, the ToC was built manually using

`\contentsline{unit}{text}{pagenumber}`

2. To manipulate how the `\contentline` material was composed, the
   `tocloft` package was used.
3. To match the page layout, the package `geometry` was used.
4. The original pdf (`QC-notes.pdf`) with the complete notes of the
   lectures was incorporated using the `pdfpages` package (139 pages).
5. Bookmarks to the final pdf file were also added manually (package
   `bookmark`).
6. Finally, a cover and a final license note extracted from the
   author's website were added.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right= 1in, top=1in]{geometry} % set the margins
\usepackage{pdfpages}% import the pdf
\usepackage[open]{bookmark} % add bookmarks to the pdf file
    
\usepackage{tocloft}% configure the ToC
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3ex}      % vertical space before the title
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{1em }         % space before the numner (like Lecture 1:)
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6.5em }     % width of the chapter number box
\cftsetpnumwidth{4ex}                    % width of the page number box
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large}
\cftsetrmarg{6ex plus1fil}                  % avoid hyphens 

% to cover page
\title{\bfseries Quantum Computation \\ \bigskip \normalsize Lecture notes}
\date{\vfill Latest update: April 11, 2006}
\author{John Watrous \\ Professor (on leave), Institute for Quantum Computing\\ 
    and Cheriton School of Computer Science\\   
    University of Waterloo}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % cover page
    
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page  \vspace*{3ex}\par }

    % build the ToC
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 1:}Overview of quantum information}{1}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 2:}Overview of quantum information (continued)}{6}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 3:}Superdense coding; quantum circuits, and partial measurements}{14}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 4:}Quantum Teleportation; Deutsch's Algorithm}{22}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 5:}A simple searching algorithm; the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm}{28}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 6:}Simon's algorithm}{34}{}    
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 7:}Arithmetic/number--theoretic problems; reversible computation}{39}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 8:}Phase estimation}{48}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 9:}Phase estimation (continued); the quantum Fourier transform }{55}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 10:}Order finding}{61}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 11:}Order finding (continued); reducing factoring to order finding}{66}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 12:}Grover's Algorithm}{70}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 13:}Grover’s Algorithm (continued)}{76}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 14:}Quantum information revisited}{81}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 15:}Quantum information revisited (continued)}{88}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 16:}Quantum error correction}{94}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 17:}General quantum errors; CSS codes}{102}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 18:}Quantum Key Distribution}{109}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 19:}Impossibility of Quantum Bit Commitment}{115}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 20:}Bell inequalities and nonlocality}{120}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 21:}Quantum communication complexity}{126}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {Lecture 22:}Quantum communication complexity}{133}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {About}}{140}{}

% addign the bookmarks <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\bookmark[page=1]{Cover}
\bookmark[page=2]{Contents}
\bookmark[page=3]{Lecture 1: Overview of quantum information}
\bookmark[page=8]{Lecture 2: Overview of quantum information (continued)}
\bookmark[page=16]{Lecture 3: Superdense coding; quantum circuits, and partial measurements}
\bookmark[page=24]{Lecture 4: Quantum Teleportation; Deutsch's Algorithm}
\bookmark[page=30]{Lecture 5: A simple searching algorithm; the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm}
\bookmark[page=36]{Lecture 6: Simon's algorithm}
\bookmark[page=41]{Lecture 7: Arithmetic/number-theoretic problems; reversible computation}
\bookmark[page=50]{Lecture 8: Phase estimation}
\bookmark[page=57]{Lecture 9: Phase estimation (continued); the quantum Fourier transform}
\bookmark[page=63]{Lecture 10: Order finding }
\bookmark[page=68]{Lecture 11: Order finding (continued); reducing factoring to order finding }
\bookmark[page=72]{Lecture 12: Grover's Algorithm }
\bookmark[page=78]{Lecture 13: Grover’s Algorithm (continued)}
\bookmark[page=83]{Lecture 14: Quantum information revisited}
\bookmark[page=90]{Lecture 15: Quantum information revisited (continued)}
\bookmark[page=96]{Lecture 16: Quantum error correction}
\bookmark[page=104]{Lecture 17: General quantum errors; CSS codes}
\bookmark[page=111]{Lecture 18: Quantum Key Distribution}
\bookmark[page=117]{Lecture 19: Impossibility of Quantum Bit Commitment}
\bookmark[page=122]{Lecture 20: Bell inequalities and nonlocality}
\bookmark[page=128]{Lecture 21: Quantum communication complexity}
\bookmark[page=135]{Lecture 22: Quantum communication complexity }
\bookmark[page=142]{About}

\mainmatter

\includepdf[pages=-]{QC-notes}

\chapter*{About} % license page
\parindent 0pt
\sffamily \Large
These lecture notes may be used and distributed freely, for individual study or by course instructors. They may not be sold.

These are ancient lecture notes for an introductory undergraduate course on quantum computing taught at the University of Calgary in Spring 2006. They are not being maintained.

Latest update: April 11, 2006 \bigskip

\copyright2006 John Watrous 

\end{document}
```

**OPTION**

This is another variant, using `hyperref` to create the bookmarks and also links in the ToC (new); and using `pdfpages` to generate the ToC (manually retrieved lecture titles and page numbers as before)

`\includepdf` with a`addtotoc={page number,section,level,heading,label}` (Used here section=chapter, level =0)

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1in,right= 1in,top=1in]{geometry} % set the margins
\usepackage{pdfpages}% import the pdf and make ToC
    
\usepackage{tocloft}% configure the ToC
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}      % vertical space before the title
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Lecture~}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{3ex }         % space before the number (like Lecture 1:)
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6.5em }     % width of the chapter number box
\cftsetpnumwidth{4ex}                    % width of the page number box
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large}
\cftsetrmarg{6ex plus1fil}                  % avoid hyphens 

% to cover page
\title{\bfseries Quantum Computation \\ \bigskip \normalsize Lecture notes}
\date{\vfill Latest update: April 11,2006}
\author{John Watrous \\ Professor (on leave),Institute for Quantum Computing\\  
    and Cheriton School of Computer Science\\   
    University of Waterloo}



\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,bookmarksopen]{hyperref} % bookmarks and links in ToC

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle % cover page     
    
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mainmatter

 %add pdf and build the ToC     
\includepdf[pages=-,
pagecommand={},
addtotoc={%
1,chapter,0,Overview of quantum information,Lec:1,
6,chapter,0,Overview of quantum information (continued),Lec:2,
14,chapter,0,Superdense coding; quantum circuits; and partial measurements,Lec:3,
22,chapter,0,Quantum Teleportation; Deutsch's Algorithm,Lec:4,
28,chapter,0,A simple searching algorithm; the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm,Lec:5,
36,chapter,0,Simon's algorithm,Lec:6,
39,chapter,0,Arithmetic/number--theoretic problems; reversible computation,Lec:7,
48,chapter,0,Phase estimation,Lec:8,
55,chapter,0,Phase estimation (continued) ; the quantum Fourier transform,Lec:9,
61,chapter,0,Order finding,Lec:10,
66,chapter,0,Order finding (continued) ;  reducing factoring to order finding,Lec:11,
70,chapter,0,Grover's Algorithm,Lec:12,
76,chapter,0,Grover’s Algorithm (continued),Lec:13,
81,chapter,0,Quantum information revisited,Lec:14,
88,chapter,0,Quantum information revisited (continued),Lec:15,
94,chapter,0,Quantum error correction,Lec:16,
102,chapter,0,General quantum errors; CSS codes,Lec:17,
109,chapter,0,Quantum Key Distribution,Lec:18,
115,chapter,0,Impossibility of Quantum Bit Commitment,Lec:19,
120,chapter,0,Bell inequalities and nonlocality,Lec:20,
126,chapter,0,Quantum communication complexity,Lec:21,
133,chapter,0,Quantum communication complexity,Lec:22
}]{QC-notes.pdf}
    
\chapter*{About} % license page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{About}
\parindent 0pt
\sffamily \Large
These lecture notes may be used and distributed freely,for individual study or by course instructors. They may not be sold.

These are ancient lecture notes for an introductory undergraduate course on quantum computing taught at the University of Calgary in Spring 2006. They are not being maintained.

Latest update: April 11,2006 \bigskip

\copyright2006 John Watrous 

\end{document}
```

.

Comment: This definitely work as it is a one time job. It served my purpose. I wonder if toc can be auto generated. Anyway great work...!!

Comment: @madeel Thank you for your feedback! To auto generate the ToC  I think you will need the original .tex file(s). The only really manual work I did was to get the page number from the pdf. Then it was only copy/past the titles from the web page and using an excel table to generate both list of commands,